# Очистка дисков на Vcenter

Tags: vmware

Стоит vCenter 6.7 на нем множество виртуалок,которые за все время его работы переименовывались, удалялись без удаления дисков. И теперь там огромное количество не понятных папок и vmdk файлов. И теперь стоит задача

1. Сопоставить VM с файлами vmdk и каталогами их содержащими
2. Переименовать эти каталоги и файлы vmdk без остановки VM

Подскажите как решали такую проблему или может куда копать